# Ads/Admob in .NET 8 MAUI

Tags: admob, maui, ads, collectionview, .net-8.0

I am using .NET 8 MAUI. I have a CollectionView where the user scrolls through a list of posts. I want every 10th post to be an ad. Is there any packages I can use that will show me a different ad each time that I can include in a CollectionView?

I have had a look at https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob but this only seems to be banner and Interstitial ads, which isn't what I want.

I did read something about using webview to show the ads, but I'm not too sure on how that will work.

Comment: Currently, you could use `AdMob` in MAUI by this official package: [Xamarin.Google PlayServices.Ads](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads#versions-body-tab). However, compatibility issues will occur if your framework is higher than .NET 6.0. And you can add a new feature request as per your needs [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues).

Comment: Is there any documentation or something I can use to see how I can get the native ads to show the way I need?

Comment: In MAUI, you could use the native AdMob class library directly through the Binding Native Library feature. For more information, please check [Binding Native Libraries for .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/dotnetconf-focus-on-maui/binding-native-libraries-for-dotnet-maui).